# How can I style even and odd elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use CSS pseudo-classes to select even and odd instances of list items?

I'd expect the following to produce a list of alternating colors, but instead I get a list of blue items:

```css
li { color: blue }
li:odd { color:green }
li:even { color:red }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 822, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/K3TuN/1323/

```css
li {
    color: black;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #777;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
</ul>
```

Documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
- http://caniuse.com/css-sel3 (it works almost everywhere)

Comment: Just a note perhaps: nth-child isn't supported by IE 8 and below.

Comment: You can use the ***[Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/)*** polyfill if you need to support IE8... and IE6/7 as well.

Comment: Just confirmed that even with Selectivizr `:nth-child(odd/even)` does not work in IE8.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Test screenshot: http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img746/3716/120033.png - You can get the test assets here: http://jsfiddle.net/8z9Zw/1/ - Keep in mind that jsfiddle.net doesn't support IE8 so you won't be able to test there, I had to run this test locally via VirtualBox in order to run IE8, I'm just placing the assets in jsfiddle in case you want to run your own tests. Good luck.

Comment: True, it doesn't work in IE8 as documented here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 but it does work on *every major browser*.

Comment: After all IE8 Support is nothing to worry about anymore in this case as the intended behaviour is just 'supportive'. It does not prevent the user from using the site nor from finding information. It doesn't even (most likely not) spoil the overall appearance of the website.

Answer (score 65):

The problem with your CSS lies with the syntax of your pseudo-classes.

The even and odd pseudo-classes should be:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
    color:green;
}
```

and

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color:red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q76qS/5/

Answer (score 26):

Use this:

```css
li { color:blue; }
li:nth-child(odd) { color:green; }
li:nth-child(even) { color:red; }
```

See here for info on browser support:
http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Answer (score 12):

But it's not working in IE.

Recommend using
`:nth-child(2n+1)`
`:nth-child(2n+2)`

```css
li {
    color: black;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #777;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
    <li>ho</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

the css odd and even is not support for IE.
recommend you using solution below.

Best solution:

```
li:nth-child(2n+1) { color:green; } // for odd
li:nth-child(2n+2) { color:red; } // for even

li:nth-child(1n) { color:green; }
li:nth-child(2n) { color:red; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list element 1</li>
  <li>list element 2</li>
  <li>list element 3</li>
  <li>list element 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
li:nth-child(1n) { color:green; }
li:nth-child(2n) { color:red; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list element 1</li>
  <li>list element 2</li>
  <li>list element 3</li>
  <li>list element 4</li>
</ul>
```

See browser support here :
[CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 1):

**Below is the example of even and odd css color apply**

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(even) {
    background: red;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
    background: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The first Odd.</p>
<p>The second Even.</p>
<p>The third Odd.</p>
<p>The fourth Even.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.
Odd and even are keywords that can be used to match child elements whose index is odd or even (the index of the first child is 1).

this is what you want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            li { color: blue }<br>
            li:nth-child(even) { color:red }
            li:nth-child(odd) { color:green}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>ho</li>
            <li>ho</li>
            <li>ho</li>
            <li>ho</li>
            <li>ho</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working:** nth child with number and odd even

```
.ziehharmonika:nth-child(1) h3 {  /*select number one child*/
    background-color: green;
}

.ziehharmonika:nth-child(odd) h3 {
    background-color: red;
}

.ziehharmonika:nth-child(even) h3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -9):

```
 <ul class="names" id="names_list">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">1</span><li class="part1" id="1">Ashwin Nair</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">2</span><li class="part2" id="2">Anil Reddy</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part1" id="3">Chirag</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part2" id="4">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part1" id="15">Ashwin</li></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part2" id="16">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">5</span><li class="part1" id="17">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">6</span><li class="part2" id="18">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">1</span><li class="part1" id="19">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">2</span><li class="part2" id="188">Anil Reddy</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part1" id="111">Bhavesh</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part2" id="122">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part1" id="133">Ashwin</li></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">0</span><li class="part2" id="144">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">5</span><li class="part1" id="199">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">6</span><li class="part2" id="156">Ashwin</li></a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="badge">1</span><li class="part1" id="174">Ashwin</li></a>

         </ul>    
$(document).ready(function(){
      var a=0;
      var ac;
      var ac2;
        $(".names li").click(function(){
           var b=0;
            if(a==0)
            {
              var accc="#"+ac2;
     if(ac=='part2')
     {
    $(accc).css({

    "background": "#322f28",
    "color":"#fff",
    });
     }
     if(ac=='part1')
     {

      $(accc).css({

      "background": "#3e3b34",
      "color":"#fff",
    });
     }

              $(this).css({
                "background":"#d3b730",
                "color":"#000",
            });
              ac=$(this).attr('class');
              ac2=$(this).attr('id');
    a=1;
            }
            else{

    var accc="#"+ac2;
    //alert(accc);
     if(ac=='part2')
     {
    $(accc).css({

    "background": "#322f28",
    "color":"#fff",
    });
     }
     if(ac=='part1')
     {

      $(accc).css({

      "background": "#3e3b34",
      "color":"#fff",
    });
     }

     a=0;
    ac=$(this).attr('class');
    ac2=$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).css({
                "background":"#d3b730",
                "color":"#000",
            });

            }

        });
```

Comment: This is just ... Horrible.  There are so many better ways to target even/odd elements.  
Furthermore, there's no reason to use JavaScript like this when two lines of CSS would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: prime example of what to avoid when learning to code