# Alternating classes using jQuery Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, template-engine, jquery-templates

I'd like, based on an array of data received, to produce a list of `<li>` items. Each one will have an alternating class of either "even" or "odd". Here is what I have so far:

```
<script id="news_template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        {{= title }}
    </li>
</script>
```

Looking over the documentation, I don't see anything that would easily lend itself to doing this. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

EDIT: If I could simply evaluate raw JavaScript in some way, I could simply set a variable and base my output on that in each iteration. I know jQote2 has this feature. For instance, I could do something like:

```
<% even = !even; %>
```

...and then base the class on the state of that var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had to do this last week for a table with this structure:

```
<table class='stripe' width='100%'>
  <!---awesome table with awesome rows and awesome columns--->
 < /table>
```

So I have used a couple of css lines:

```
 tr.even {background-color: #DDD;  color:Black;}
 tr.odd {background-color: #fff; color:Black;}
```

Then, using jQuery:

```
  $('table.stripe tbody tr:odd').addClass('odd');
  $('table.stripe tbody tr:even').addClass('even');
```

In your case, just use:

```
$ ('ul.stripe li:even').addClass('even');
$ ('ul.stripe li:odd').addClass('odd');
```

Which means some like "Please, Mr. jQuery, put an odd or even class depending on if tr is odd or even".

Hope it helps!

Comment: A simpler version of this approach is [in the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items).  It uses the nth-child selector.

Comment: @JackieChiles, awesome!, quite elegant solution, gonna use it from this moment on!

Comment: That nth-child selector is super cool. If I didn't have to make this site compatible with IE7, I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
        {{if ($index %2) == 0}}
            <div id="item odd">
        {{else}}
            <div id="item even">
        {{/if}}
```