# Using JS to wrap pairs of <li> in divs

Tags: javascript, list

It seems like I need some pretty basic JS help. I an trying to make a script that will add a `<div>` around every two listelements in a `<ul>`. The amount of list elements are not under my control, neither is the height of each element. But i need a way to ensure that every pair (shown side by side) takes up the same anount of space.

Hope you can help

Thank you.

So from..

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

to...

```
 <ul>
     <div>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </div>
     <div>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </div>
     <div>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </div>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want `<div>` elements? To format `<li>` items? If so - why not use css directly on `<li>`?

Comment: `div`s aren't valid children of [`ul`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL); only `li` can be children of `ul`. This question suffers from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using jquery you can try:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                var lis = $("li");
                for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=2) {
                    lis.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div></div>");
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what jquery's $("li") does, but if it returns a list of all li elements on the page, this could so break when there is more then one list on the page. Edit: yes, it does break with lists having an odd amount of child-li's, it would move the first li of the second list into the first list, I don't think you'd want that ;)

Comment: no it does not break if you have an odd number of lis, and as for the $("li") selector, it is the only one I can use following his html (I'm pretty sure he has classes and everything in his real code that he will use as selectors)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I substituted ("<div></div>") with ("<ul class="subList"><li class="subListElement"></li></ul>") instead, so everything should check out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping in extra non-semantic elements, try using the CSS :even and :odd classes instead.  More info found at:
[Using CSS :even and :odd pseudo-classes with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items)

Answer (score 0):

This gives the desired output:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        var str="",fHtml="";
        var i=0;
        $("li").each(function(key,val){
            str+="<li>"+$(this).html()+"</li>";
            if(++i==2) { 
                    i=0;    
                    fHtml+="<div>"+str+"</div>";
                    str=""; 
                }
         });
         $("ul").html(fHtml)
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
        <li>first Div</li>
        <li>first Div</li>
        <li>second div</li>
        <li>second div</li>
        <li>third div</li>
        <li>third div</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show that list of elements in pairs of two next to eachother, independent of their size, you can just use CSS3:

Define `float:left` for all li elements, and then use the `:nth-child(odd)` selector to add `clear: left;` for all odd li elements (1st, 3rd, 5th, etc)

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/e63Rv/