# jQuery even position DOM wrapping

Tags: jquery, dom, selector

I have following [html](/questions/tagged/html) code and i want to `close div` and wrap two `ul` inside of `div`.

`Ul` will be more and more because it will dynamically added.

```
<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv">
    <ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    </ul><ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want output as below.

```
<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv">
    <ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv">
    <ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    </ul><ul class="span6 pull-left">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**I have tried**

```
$('.viewDetailDiv ul:even').not(':first').css('margin-left','0').wrapAll('<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv">');
$('.viewDetailDiv ul:nth-of-type(2)').nextUntil('ul').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv">');

$('.viewDetailDiv ul').each(function()
{
    $(this).nextUntil('ul:even').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv" />');
});

$('.viewDetailDiv ul').each(function()
{
    $(this).nextUntil('ul:even').prev().wrapAll('<div class="span9 well viewDetailDiv" />');
    console.log($(this).nextUntil('ul:even'));
});
```

none of the above code solve my problem.

So if you guys see the error please let me know so i can correct myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
     var uls = $("ul");
     for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i+=2) {
          uls.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='span9 well viewDetailDiv'></div>");
     }
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xw3r/)

Logic from [Using JS to wrap pairs of <li> in divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849504/using-js-to-wrap-pairs-of-li-in-divs)