# How to style every other item in a list as bold?

Tags: html, css

I want to style my list like this:

1. **List item**
2. List item
3. **List item**
4. List item
5. **List item**

^^ you see here the first is bold, second is normal, third is bold, and so on.

I want to make the same thing dynamically on my list.

Comment: What kind of a list is it? A `<ul>`? Can you show some code?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use css3 selector `nth-child`:

```
ol>li:nth-child(odd){
    font-weight:bold;
}​
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/FwTBU/

Comment: +1, but consider posting the code here as well so it's preserved for the ages.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job

```
ul.zebra li:nth-child(odd),
ol.zebra li:nth-child(odd)
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And your markup would be

```
<ul class="zebra">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ol class="zebra">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ol>
```

```css
ul.zebra li:nth-child(odd),
ol.zebra li:nth-child(odd)
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="zebra">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>


<ol class="zebra">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ol li
{
  font-weight:normal
}

ol li:nth-child(odd){
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:nth-child(odd) { font-weight:bold }
li:nth-child(even) { font-weight:normal }
```