# Even rows does not have background color

Tags: css

I have the following JSFiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KqFsy/)

With the following CSS:

```
.showlangs tr:even {
    background-color: #DFFAFF;
}
```

But the even rows are not showing the background color. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should instead be

```
.showlangs tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #DFFAFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KqFsy/1/

Comment: Sitepoint has a great reference section for CSS, including [pseudo selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses), which is what you're using here.

Comment: It looks like its working fine to me .. which browser are you using?

Comment: WOW nvm it works fine in FF... using IE8. Anyway to also show up in IE <= 8?

Comment: @SiKni8 it works fine for me. Which browser are you viewing in?

Comment: IE8 which doesnt support pseudo selectors i am guessing. any work around?

Comment: You can make it work in IE8 with JavaScript, but IMO that's not really necessary. This is a perfect example of progressive enhancement. Your users aren't missing the content in IE8, it's just enhanced in browsers that can support it.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.showlangs tr:even').css('background-color', '#DFFAFF');
});

(I used JQuery which works both in IE and FF)