# Even/Odd to determine CSS class

Tags: php, css

I've read a lot of information about the determination of a even/odd number and using it to change the class of a div.

In my case I want to switch the position of divs called MessagePicture and MessageText every new message posted.

1. Picture left, Text right
2. Picture right, Text left
3. Picture left, Text right
4. ect.

This is the code I am using to display the messages, I also included one of my tries to get the even/odd code to work.

Can anyone tell me what I should change to get it to work?

```
    <?PHP

    $Query =
    "
            SELECT
                ID,
                NameBox,
            MessageBox,
            Code
        FROM
            messages
            ORDER BY
                ID
            DESC LIMIT 10
    ";

    $Result = mysql_query($Query);

        if(!$Result)
            {
            echo 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
            }

        else
            {
            if(mysql_num_rows($Result) == 0)
                {
                    echo 'No results';
                }

                else
                    {
                    $i = 0;
                $class = (++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';
                    while
                    ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))

                        echo '

<div id="MessageWrapper">
    <div id="MessagePicture" class="'.$class.'">                                                                                
        <style>                                             
        #MessagePicture { 
        background-image: url(../../../Images/'.stripslashes($Row['Code']).'.png);  
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: center
        </style>
        </div>

    <div id="MessageText" class="'.$class.'">

        <div id="MessageTitle">

            <h1>'.$Row['NameBox'].'</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="MessageContent">                                                   
            <p>'.nl2br($Row['MessageBox']).'</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>  

';}}}?>
```

Comment: If you format your code properly, it will be easier for people to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Side note: You are defining new HTML elements with the same ID over and over again (MessageContent, MessageText etc). You should either add a Number (for examle `_$i`) to make them unique or make a class out of it.

Comment: I do not understand, the ID names are unique, they are all different divs, they only share a part of the name (Message). It is for my own reference to understand what part of the website they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$i` always stays `0`. Add `$i++` in the while loop to increment it.

You can do that in one line:

```
$class = ($i++ % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
```

Full Example:

```
$i = 0;
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
  $class = ($i++ % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
  //echo ...
}
```

Comment: or simple `(++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';`

Comment: I tried, and all of the results (messages) stay even.
It does not increment.

$i = 0;
$class = (++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
echo '

Comment: Could you update your question with the modified code so we can see where you put the increment?

Comment: Place the line inside of the while loop.

Comment: Placing that exact code in the while loop breaks the display of the messages. No messages are displayed, only the empty shells of the divs.

Comment: That's because you removed too many brackets. I updated the answer with a complete example.

Comment: I do not want to open a new question so I hope I can ask you here: because of all the changes with the even/odd, it broke the code to determine the background image of the MessagePicture. All picutures are now the same. It shouldn't do that, while looking into the parsed source code I can clearly see different codes for each message.

Comment: That's because you have no unique IDs, as I stated earlier. Open a new question for it if you want to, but this the reason.

Comment: I would open a new question if I knew what to ask.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer to your exact problem, but since any markup already carries information on which of child element rows are even and which are odd, and since CSS is able to differentiate between these, you can achieve this using pure CSS, which is what I boldly offer here.

Use CSS selectors `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` to select even and odd children, respectively. That way you also don't have to change or tag your markup. An example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
    <li>Pears</li>
    <li>Pineapples</li>
</ul>
```

```
li:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: silver;
}

li:nth-child(odd) /* or leave this one out altogether */
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Check the following, rather authoritative page for more details and usage (like `nth-child(5n+3)`):

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: This will not work with every browser though (see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items))

Comment: @GeraldSchneider True, true. I would still do it though. Internet Explorer 8 market share is below 20% and dwindling. But most people are more conservative with the solution compatibility than me.