# While / For Loop for alternating CSS class?

Tags: php, css

I wrote a simple while loop:

```
while($fetch = $stm->fetchAll()) {
    echo '<tr class=""'>;
    echo '<td>' . $fetch['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

How can I make the class="" alternate everytime so that every other row is white and every other row is grey?  I already have the CSS class "greyRow" but don't know how to logically use it to make them alternate in PHP.

I'd assume I'd need a for loop, but how do I use it for what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my method:

```
while($fetch = $stm->fetchAll()) {

  if( !isset( $row_num ) ) $row_num = 1; // at first $row_num does not exist so create it and make uneven (start with 1)
  $row_class = (++$row_num % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd'; // then check whether $row_num is odd or even and assign it the corresponding class name

  echo '<tr class="'.$row_class.'">';
  echo '<td>' . $fetch['name'] . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to implement a variable to "count"

```
$odd_row = 1;
while($fetch = $stm->fetchAll()) {
    if ($odd_row == 0) 
        echo '<tr>';
    else
        echo '<tr class="greyRow">';
    echo '<td>' . $fetch['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $odd_row = !$odd_row;
}
```

But there are better ways, using strictly CSS.

[Using CSS :even and :odd pseudo-classes with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a counter variable if `$counter % 2 == 0` (or `!($counter % 2)`) you're on an even numbered row. Otherwise it's odd.

```
$counter = 1;
while($fetch = $stm->fetchAll()) {
    echo '<tr class="', (!($counter % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd'), '">';
    echo '<td>' . $fetch['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $counter++;
}
```

You can also just try an [`nth-child`](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) CSS selector and avoid doing this in PHP at all. It's not cross browser, however. If you need to support IE < 8, you'll need to do the above.

Example:

```
#your-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
   // style odd rows differently
}
```