# Coloring rows with css

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to color row without using JS, only CSS?

Example:

```
<p>  First row row row row ro...... row
     second row row row  .......... row
     third row row orw row row..... row
</p>
```

So every even/odd row will be colored.
Rows are not tagged!

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Comment: Not even close to duplicate. I don't have html element tags in every row.. Just on start and end of article.

Comment: Are you just using `<p>` tags and letting them naturally run on to the next line?

Comment: I don't use anything to break the line. The max-width of div breaks the lines.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/NaTj5/94/

Comment: I cant use tags in every line.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible to achieve that by pure CSS, the  closest thing we can do is using `::first-line` pseudo element to alter the color the paragraph only for first line: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/yfo62cz4/

Comment: There is a `first-line` pseudo but apart from that I don't think this coloring can be achieved with your current markup using only CSS.

Comment: Only available with JS.

Comment: Thank you for this. I know it can be done with JS but I thought it could be done with css too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using an image with two different colors.

Set the image as background for your paragraph tag and stretch it to 100% width and double line-height.

```
p
{
    background-image: url('http://s14.directupload.net/images/140912/kdn4j3iz.png');
    background-size: 100% 3em;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

The background-image which is used looks like this ( original size is 1px x 2px ): 
[image]

The outcome should look like this:
[image]

DEMO on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fmac6kp/2/

Comment: This is the closest thing.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to use a stripped background to solve your problem. No tagged rows! The only issue is that you have to set the line height. No big deal!

Please see below:

HTML:

```
<p> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut maximus tortor, in elementum arcu. Vivamus bibendum rutrum arcu, vitae feugiat risus dignissim non. Duis quis mauris elit. Donec non sem eleifend purus molestie semper. Mauris bibendum nunc vitae ipsum tempor, sed gravida nibh gravida. Proin nec diam consequat, tristique leo consectetur, hendrerit dui. Nulla quam augue, suscipit a suscipit et, eleifend nec tellus. Nunc ultrices in tortor vel condimentum. Fusce lectus massa, ullamcorper at aliquet tincidunt, efficitur at metus. Morbi pharetra lorem vel ultrices varius. Nunc ut mollis lectus. Proin vehicula nisl in lectus tincidunt, mattis ullamcorper lectus congue. Integer tempus tortor sed tincidunt semper. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean id viverra risus, a sagittis ex.     
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    /* credits : http://lea.verou.me/demos/css3-patterns.html */
    background-color: #0ae;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);

    background-size: 4em 4em; /* should be 2x line-height */
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Please try this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dh5xt3gq/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #CCC
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
background: #FFF
}
```

Comment: Tr? I'm not using table, neither I don' have html element tags in every row.