# :not vs :nth-child - which one should I prefer?

Tags: html, css

I have a list with multiple `<li>` and I want to add margin between all of them.

Which one of the following should I prefer ? (If any) Why is it better than the other ?

1. `li:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 5px; }`

or

2. `li:nth-child(n+2) { margin-top: 5px; }`

[This page](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) shows that the `:not` selector has better browser support than `:nth-child`. (as `:nth-child` doesn't work in FF3) And I am after wide browser support. That page is outdated a bit and so I thought to ask the wise community here. Is there any reason I should prefer one to another?

Comment: Generally, I just set `margin-bottom` and then use `:last-child` to  remove the style on the last element. From what I can tell, this has the highest browser support.

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5080787/1524085

Comment: For a more up-to-date source of browser support tables, check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/

Comment: this might help: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: @Jon : That's an alternative. :last-child selector's support is exactly similar to :not - as per QuirkMode and the link to the browser support page I wrote in the question. 

"last-child got better support than :nth-child I can see. But if I am to use last child I have to assign 2 selector values..one for assigning style to all li and one for removing the style from last li.

Is it somehow better(because it's short and size becomes less) to use just :not in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best browser support you'll find will be to put spacing as a `margin-top` and remove it on the first one with `:first-child`. `:first-child` has a better support than the rest of those pseudo-selectors and is supported by <del>IE8</del> IE7 and better.

Besides, doing things this way will mean that when you only have 1 element, you won't have a useless margin, which would be the case with your mindset.

If you have to support older IEs, then I think you'll have to use JS.