# XSLT differing column style global

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have the following problem:

I have a xml file and created a xslt to display the contents nicely. The data is a table with three column. Currently I define the style globally:

```
<style> table td {text-align:right; padding-right:10px; }</style>
```

Now for styleguide reasons I need to have a different style for each row. E.g. text-align left for column 1 and text-align right for column2. I could add the style to each td but this would make maintenance cumbersome and prone for bugs.

I found the `colgroup` but I am not sure how to define the alignment etc. So far I understood that I need to add `colgroup{}` to `<style></style>` and inside the `{}` have several `col{}` "children"; one for each column.

```
<style> table colgroup{col{align:right}col{align:right }col{align:left }}  </style>
```

I get no errors but there is no effect on my displayed xml file in the browser.

Is it even possible / allowed?:
[link](http://ln.hixie.ch/?count=1&start=1070385285)
Quite old so I am not sure if it still applies.

PS: I am really new to xml and xslt. So there might be an easy solution but I have not found it so far.

Comment: This is probably more a CSS issue, rather than XSLT. Try this question, which I think might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Comment: Especially if you're new to XSLT, don't start writing any XSLT code until you know what HTML you want to generate. If you don't know what HTML you want to generate, then your problem isn't an XSLT problem.

Comment: The xslt as such is finished. Management is satisfied but wants the style of each column to match the style of the app that is used to generate the xml files. E.g. the first and third column have to be left bound and the second column right bound. @Tim C How do I do this for columns?

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thx! That did it: `<style>table tr td:nth-child(even){ text-align:right ; padding-right:30px; } tr td:nth-child(odd){ text-align:left ; padding-right:30px; }</style>`

Comment: Another question: Now they want that the background alternates each row so it matches the app. I did this by adding `tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#ebebeb;} tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#f5f5f5; }` . My problem is now that the color of the head of the table also follows this rule. I tried by defining a class `table tr.head th {...}` (`<tr class="head"><th/><th>Standard Contract</th><th/></tr>` or by defining `table th {...}` which works for the font size. But the background is still the alternating one.

Comment: I also tried with the !important keyword or with adding the style directly to the table tr "element" (which works for the font size). How can I override the global background color?