# Responsive chess colored elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple rows of equal elements and I'm trying to do chess background arrangement for them.

For example:

```css
body {
            max-width: 600px;
        }
        article {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        article:nth-child(2n) {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        article:nth-child(2n + 1) {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        article:nth-child(2n + 5) {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        article:nth-child(2n + 6) {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        article:nth-child(2n + 10) {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        article:nth-child(2n + 9) {
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

Is there any way to do chess arrangement like that clear and descriptive (maybe using :nth-child selector) for one, two, three and four column arrangement using only CSS (maybe some JS).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to take a look at the odd and even pseudo classes:

```
article:nth-child(odd)
article:nth-child(even)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Example_selectors

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080787/5001964

**Update #1:** working excample for even an odd elements and not losing the chess pattern with responsiveness (JS required) -- open it full screen to trigger the window resize event

```js
function getNumberOfItemsPerRow(list) {
  var counter = 0;
  var firstRowOffsetTop = list[0].offsetTop;

  list.forEach(function(square) {
    if (square.offsetTop === firstRowOffsetTop) {
      counter += 1;
    }
  });

  return counter;
}

function removePreviousColors(list) {
 list.forEach(function(square) {
   square.className = '';
  });
}

function chessColorize() {

var squares = document.querySelectorAll('li');
 var itemsPerRow = getNumberOfItemsPerRow(squares);
  var classToAdd;
  var oddLine = true;
  
  removePreviousColors(squares);

  squares.forEach(function(square, index) {

    if (itemsPerRow % 2) {
      classToAdd = index % 2 ? 'color1' : 'color2';
    } else {
      if (oddLine) {
        classToAdd = index % 2 ? 'color1' : 'color2';
      } else {
        classToAdd = index % 2 ? 'color2' : 'color1';
      }
    }

    if ((index + 1) % itemsPerRow === 0) {
      oddLine = !oddLine;
    }

    square.classList.add(classToAdd);
  });
}



chessColorize();

window.addEventListener('resize', chessColorize);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}

li.color1 {
  background-color: red;
}

li.color2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: When a row breaks after an even element, the pattern is no longer chessboard-like. Any chance to make this responsive as per OP's title?

Comment: @le_m Just updated my previous answer with a working JS solution

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2knX8/) I changed your snippet, use `@media` for three, two and one column.

```css
body {
            max-width: 600px;
        }
        article {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        article{
            background-color: orange;
        }

article:nth-child(-2n+4), 
article:nth-child(4) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+7), 
article:nth-child(8) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+12), 
article:nth-child(24) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+31), 
article:nth-child(32) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+40), 
article:nth-child(40) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+47), 
article:nth-child(48) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+56), 
article:nth-child(56) ~ article:nth-child(-2n+63) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(new)`:

```css
div > div {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gray;
}

div > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```