# Avoid one single <li> tag getting styled by css

Tags: html, css

I'm not a pro with CSS and I've been struggling with this for hours.
So I have this in the CSS:

```
li { margin-bottom:6px;}
```

I want the photos in a gallery to have bottom margins. But in my site menu, I use `<li>` tags too, and they are affected by this rule.

How can I avoid a style conflict between the photos and the menu items?

This image has white space between the purple and the black line--that's the margin-bottom.

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials for css and if I learned it so can you, come on this is something from start from basics try working besides asking for every simple thing, like that you will never learn...

Comment: See this question on how to style odds. You may be able to get that to work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, inside the `<li>` element, you can declare a style using the `class` attribute. For example:

```
<li class="menu">
```

Then, in your stylesheet, you can specifically refer to this class of list item with the `.` operator:

```
li.menu { margin-bottom: 6px; }
```

As remarked on in the comments, you should take the time to read/watch a tutorial. [Here's one from Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css#intro-to-css) that's designed as an introduction

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude an element using the CSS 'not' property. Here's how to:

1. set a class for those elements you don't want to be affected by general CSS like: `<li class="excluded"></li>`
2. Change your CSS to

   `li:not(.excluded){
       margin-bottom:6px;
   }`