# Align odd value list iteam using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need to align my odd number list iteam in center. Mean if i have five list iteam like below then last li should align center others should align side by side in mobile device.

```
<ul>
<li> name1</li>
<li> name2</li>
<li> name3</li>
<li> name4</li>
<li> name5</li>
</ul>
```

So fist i need to validate li count whether it's ending witj odd number or even number then i need to align last li center of the screen.

Comment: Is the data in the list guaranteed to be presented in such a way where the data will be in ascending order? If so, the CSS solutions below will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As JS just set's the CSS attribs to fit anyway, you might as well check out if a pure css solution fit's your problem.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080748/1614903

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data will not be presented in ascending order, then a JavaScript solution may be required. See my example for a proof of concept. The CSS solutions will be fine when the data is presented in ascending order.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var list1 = document.querySelector('#list1');
  var listItems = list1.querySelectorAll('li');

  for (var li of listItems) {
    addCenterAlignToListItem(li);
  }
});

function addCenterAlignToListItem(li) {
  var txt = li.textContent;
  // RegEx matches a number at the end of the string.
  var num = txt.match(/\d+$/);
  
  if (!num) {
    // There was no number at the
    // end of the string.
    return;
  } else {
    // Get the string from the
    // regex match.
    num = num.pop();
  }

  if (num % 2 === 1) {
    // This is odd
    li.classList.add('centered');
  }
}
```

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  The list is intentionally
  out of order.
-->

<ul id="list1">
  <li>name2</li>
  <li>name5</li>
  <li>name1</li>
  <li>name3</li>
  <li>name4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you!

```css
.list li {
    text-align: inherit;
}
.list li:nth-child(odd) {
    text-align: center;
}
.list li:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li> name1</li>
  <li> name2</li>
  <li> name3</li>
  <li> name4</li>
  <li> name5</li>
</ul>
```