# Determining odd and even numbers

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? 
What I am trying to do is looping through the list and assign a background colour for odd and even numbers.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.links-wrapper li');


for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
    if(box[i] % 2 === 0){
     box[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
     box[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}
```

Comment: `box[i]` will return an element, not a number, so `% 2` won't work.

Comment: Use CSS for this instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080787/362536

Comment: are these odd/even numbers the **content** of the `li`, or the index?

Comment: also, no point in making an executable snippet if there's no chance the snippet can execute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `box[i]` to `i`

```
for(var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
    if(i % 2 === 0){
        box[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
        box[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}
```

Else you can use css psuedo selector

```css
.links-wrapper li:nth-child(even) {
  color: red
}

.links-wrapper li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<ul class="links-wrapper">
  <li> 1</li>
  <li> 2</li>
  <li> 3</li>
  <li> 4</li>
  <li> 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Grrrr `<li>`'s allowed parents are `<ul>` `<ol>` `<menu>` or even obsolete `<dir>` but not `<div>`

Comment: @Kaiido apologies for the mistake.Have updated the answer