# odd - even background colors to groups

Tags: html, css

I want to have alternate background colors to **groups** and not for elements. Which means [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items) `li:nth-child(even)` and `li:nth-child(odd)` will not work for me. Below is the code what I have done. It works fine when sequence is maintained E.g A,B,C,D...

It creates issue when sequence is not maintained E.g B,A,C,D

This can be solved by adding odd/even class to alternate groups using JS which I want to avoid.

**Is there any CSS only solution?**.

```css
.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a,
.c,
.e {
  background: #ddd
}

.b,
.d {
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<h3>works fine when sequence is maintained as below</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
<h3>When sequence is not followed this is what happens.</h3>  
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
<h3>Below is ths output needed if sequence is not followed.</h3>  
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">B</div>
  <div class="a">B</div>
  <div class="a">B</div>
  <div class="b">A</div>
  <div class="b">A</div>
  <div class="b">A</div>
  <div class="b">A</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Comment: @fubar its for odd/even element. It dose not work for groups.

Comment: @dipikapatil, please explain your question in more detail then, as it is not clear what you're trying to achieve if not odd/even colours.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible with CSS alone. There is no `nth-of-class` or similar selector in CSS.

Comment: @fubar in that case JS is only solution for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You just change a bit on your HTML structure:

```css
.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.group:nth-child(even) div {
  background: #ddd
}

.group:nth-child(odd) div {
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="group group-b">
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-a">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="group group-c">
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-d">
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-e">
    <div class="e">E</div>
    <div class="e">E</div>
    <div class="e">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-a">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-b">
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-c">
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group group-d">
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Editing html would be tough rather I would use JS

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper .a::nth-of-type(0){
background:#ccc;
}
.wrapper .a::nth-of-type(2){
background:#ddd;
}
```

Comment: Do you really think this will work ?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: yes, it worked for the different type. please test maybe it worked for you.