# How set css to alternating rows in angular 4

Tags: css, angular, rows, alternating

I would like to define a class to alternating rows in angular 4, how to do this?

HTML

```
 <div class="scrollbars">
            <div  *ngFor="let path of Xyzpaths">
                    <div>{{path.xyz}}</div>
                    <div>{{path.salesItem}}</div>
                    <div>{{path.path1}}</div>
                    <div>{{path.path2}}</div>
            </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.odd  {   background-color: #f2f9ff;} 
.even {   background-color: #eceff3; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS :even and :odd pseudo-classes with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, you can use the odd and even local variables in the ngFor, something like this:

```html
<div class="scrollbars">
    <div *ngFor="let path of Xyzpaths index as i; let even = even; let odd = odd" 
     [ngClass]="{ myOddClass: odd, myEvenClass: even }">
        <div>{{path.xyz}}</div>
        <div>{{path.salesItem}}</div>
        <div>{{path.path1}}</div>
        <div>{{path.path2}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables).

Comment: This solution is very straightforward, superb

Answer (score 8):

Use CSS's [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```
scrollbars > div:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f9ff;}
scrollbars > div:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #eceff3;}
```

Try to avoid adding template logic where you don't need to, and in this case, you don't need to -- CSS can do it all and is *orders of magnitude more efficient* than using a template directive.