# How can I create a html table with colors by row and by column?

Tags: html, css

I have seen this image showing a very nice table:

[image]

I have html code that gives color to every even line. Every year column and subcolumns have a color too. Is there a way to have a new different mixed color for the cells in year coluns and even rows and a new different mixed color for the cells in year coluns and odd rows, just like in the picture?
I do not want to use something like:

```
.mixed_odd {background-color: #44ff99}
.mixed_even {background-color: #99ff99}
```

because my page will have many rows, more than 200 in some cases and it takes a lot of time to set the color to those columns manually. Is there a fast css way to do it like in the picture?

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.beta td {
  text-align: center;
}

TH.Title {
  background-color: #A0E0A0
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #bbffcc;
}

.Year2016 {
  background-color: #ffff99
}

.Year2017 {
  background-color: #ccff99
}

.Year2018 {
  background-color: #ffff99
}
```

```html
<TABLE class="beta" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="6" border="1">
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan="2">code</TH>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan="2">Text</TH>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan="2">Text</TH>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan="2">Text</TH>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan="2">Text</TH>
    <th class="Year2016" colspan="2">2016 Items</th>
    <th class="Year2017" colspan="2">2017 items</th>
    <th class="Year2018" colspan="2">2018 Items</th>
  </tr>

  <TR>
    <TH class="Year2016">Item 1</TH>
    <TH class="Year2016">Item 2</TH>
    <TH class="Year2017">Item 1</TH>
    <TH class="Year2017">Item 2</TH>
    <TH class="Year2018">Item 1</TH>
    <TH class="Year2018">Item 2</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>text 1</TD>
    <TD>text 2</TD>
    <TD>text 3</TD>
    <TD>text 4</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">5</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">6</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">7</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">8</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">9</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">10</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>text 1</TD>
    <TD>text 2</TD>
    <TD>text 3</TD>
    <TD>text 4</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">5</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">6</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">7</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">8</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">9</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">10</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>text 1</TD>
    <TD>text 2</TD>
    <TD>text 3</TD>
    <TD>text 4</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">5</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">6</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">7</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">8</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">9</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">10</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>text 1</TD>
    <TD>text 2</TD>
    <TD>text 3</TD>
    <TD>text 4</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">5</TD>
    <TD class="Year2016">6</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">7</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017">8</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">9</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018">10</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: `:nth-child(even`, `:nth-child(odd)`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: I don't think this question is a dup to the suggested question, to get the result you want, check this out https://jsfiddle.net/kendra_chu/5f316pct/1/. For your specific table, you want to be able to highlight the first row every other child except for the first 5, then 2nd row is every 2 child, 3rd row on, you want every 2 children from 5th column on and so on.

Comment: It is easy to judge, hard to understand. No it is not a dublicate. I DO NOT use lists. It is a different approach. See the image to understand what I want to make: https://imgur.com/a/No5rgQK Any fast css way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS already has rules for odd and even childs.

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

You can set an ID for the table and work your style from that, so you won't have to style each element of the table manually. Suppose you have a `<table id="beta">`, you can write your CSS like:

```
#beta tr:nth-child(even) {color:limegreen;}
#beta tr:nth-child(odd) {color:lime;}
```

This will result in your even rows styled limegreen and your odd ones, lime. The same can be applied to `<td>`'s and whatever. [This is another example but using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items), from a SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `<'col>`, thank this you can color a whole column.

I give you a link for the syntax: https://html.com/tags/col/