# How to color in blue every even value from the array in an <ul> element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a  in the HTML and i need  to get all the  of an values of an array and display them in a

in this  . But every even value from the array must be with blue color.

So far i have extracted the the values and created the

structure in the HTML , but i am not sure how to check the even values from the array . Should i do it with an IF statement in the FOR , or there is another simpler way through the DOM . I can not use CSS . 
This is my code : 
var animals = ['Dog', 'Donkey', 'Horse', 'Pig', 'Sheep', 'Chicken', 'Duck',
'Cat', 'Rabbit'];

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length ; i++) {
    var animal = animals[i];
    var ul = document.getElementById('animals')
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(animal));
    ul.appendChild(li);
```

//I have tried with an IF statement , but it is not working. //

```
 if (animal[i] % 2 === 0) {
      animal[i].style.color = '0000FF';
  }
}
```

Frameworks are not allowed

CSS as well ,as it is for a homework for my Javascript for Begginers course :)

I have seen how to achieve it with CSS and nth:child , but i can not use it here. I am sorry if the question seems a little "stupid" ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items

Comment: Any reason you can't use CSS, rather than javascript?  `#animals li:nth-child(even) { color: blue; }`

Comment: You appear to mean even/odd based on list item _number_, not _values_ … Your values are `Dog`, `Donkey` etc. – those aren’t “even” or “uneven” to begin with. `animal[i] % 2 === 0` – so `animal[i]` would be one of those mentioned values; did you really expect `'Dog' % 2 === 0` to make much sense here …? If anything, you’d want to look at the loop index variable `i` here, and check what the value of _that_ modulo 2 is …

Comment: _“I can not use CSS”_ - please don’t state stuff like this, without giving any explanation as to _why_ not - otherwise I’m gonna assume that simply means _you_ can’t, due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: CSS as well ,as it is for a homework for my Javascript for Begginers course :)

I have seen how to achieve it with CSS and nth:child , but i can not use it here. I am sorry if the question seems a little "stupid"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS :even and :odd pseudo-classes with list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you "can not use CSS" here are the two issues with your code...

Firstly, you're trying to do a numerical operation on a string

```
if (animal[i] % 2 === 0)
```

Your array contains string items, therefore this is (as [04FS says in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321805/how-to-color-in-blue-every-even-value-from-the-array-in-an-ul-element-with-jav/58322167#comment103002470_58321805)) effectively saying

```
if ("Dog" % 2 === 0)
```

So instead, just check the **index**...

```
if (i % 2 === 0)
```

Secondly, you're then trying to set a CSS style on the string object in the array, which obviously isn't going to work, because "dog" doesn't have a `style` property

```
animal[i].style.color = '0000FF';
```

You should be setting it on the `li` object you've just created...

```
li.style.color = '0000FF';
```

So the result should be...

```
if (i % 2 === 0) {
  li.style.color = '0000FF';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw you dont want CSS or something. And also it is for homework. I think with this you can pass the exercise. Pure js.

```js
var animals = ['Dog', 'Donkey', 'Horse', 'Pig', 'Sheep', 'Chicken', 'Duck', 'Cat', 'Rabbit'];


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("UL");
  x.setAttribute("id", "myUL");
  document.body.appendChild(x);

  for (var index = 0; index < animals.length; index++) {
    var y = document.createElement("LI");
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      y.style.color = '#0000ff'
    }
    var t = document.createTextNode(animals[index]);
    y.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(y);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a UL and LI element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thank you George, that is what i needed to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in `Javascript`  below code will work for you **But load `javascript` after the `HTML`(means at the end of the `HTML` code)**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>My List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="animals"></div>
<script>
       var animals = ['Dog', 'Donkey', 'Horse', 'Pig', 'Sheep', 'Chicken', 'Duck', 'Cat', 'Rabbit'];
            var ul = document.createElement('UL');
            for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
                var animal = animals[i];
                var li = document.createElement('LI')
                ul.appendChild(li);
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(animal));
                document.getElementById('animals').appendChild(li)

                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    li.style.color = "blue"
                }
            }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, ther is simple solution in `CSS` also

```css
li:nth-child(even){
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
</ul>
```