# Nested <ul> odd / even css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

We have nested unordered lists with product data.
For

```
<ul class="data_holder">
```

we want odd/even background colors.

```
ul.data_holder:odd => background: #ccc
```

```
ul.data_holder:even => background: #FFF
```

Our whole structure looks like this (as you see, our ul.data_holder sits inside an "li" element of the parent unordered list:

```
<ul class="row_holder">
 <li class="row">
   <ul class="data_holder">
     <li class="data">Data 1</li><li class="data">Data 2</li><li class="data">Data 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  <li class="row">
   <ul class="data_holder">
     <li class="data">Data 1</li><li class="data">Data 2</li><li class="data">Data 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  <li class="row">
   <ul class="data_holder">
     <li class="data">Data 1</li><li class="data">Data 2</li><li class="data">Data 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  <li class="row">
   <ul class="data_holder">
     <li class="data">Data 1</li><li class="data">Data 2</li><li class="data">Data 3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: similar question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a CSS to the `li`, not to the `ul` which is inside the `li`. Try Below CSS:

```css
    ul.row_holder li:nth-child(odd) ul{
          background-color:red;
    }
    ul.row_holder li:nth-child(even) ul{
          background-color:black;
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you very much. I was trying all sorts of CSS. APart from your solution. Works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS structure, nth-child(odd/even). With this code, you'll be able to have different stylings for odd/even objects in a list like this unordered list. Since you have a first `<ul>` with `<li>` elements inside, I would suggest you do this selector on the `.row` elements in your HTML.

```
.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your example is in this fiddle I made with the code above: https://jsfiddle.net/u3t8n9ra/