# Timeline with images in center

Tags: html, css, psd

Can someone please help me?!

I'm trying to code a PSD file to HTML and CSS, but I'm struggling with one of the sections. Here's an image of what I want to do:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdmyi.png)

The problem is I don't know how to put the image in the timeline line. I tried to add the image in the ::after psuedo, but I don't think this is the right way of doing that.

This is my HTML Code :

```
<section class="about">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
    <div class="container left">
            <div class="content">
                <h5>JULY 2010<br> Our Humble Beginnings</h5>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum officia labore fugit nihil nulla laboriosam praesentium harum ut, odio ea facere, recusandae reprehenderit repellat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container right">
            <div class="content">
                <h5>January 2011<br> Facing Startups Battles</h5>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum officia labore fugit nihil nulla laboriosam praesentium harum ut, odio ea facere, recusandae reprehenderit repellat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
    .about .wrapper{
        padding: 80px 10%;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .about .wrapper::after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 6px;
        background: red;
    }

    .about h5{
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 1em;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
    }

    .about .container{
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        top: 60px;
        margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    }

    .about .container::after{
        content: 'How Can I Add an Image Here in this circle?';
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 20px;
        right: -104px;
        background-color: blue; /* Just because there is no image */
        background-image: url(assets/img/about-1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .left{
        text-align: right;
    }

    .right{
        text-align: right;
    }

    .content{
        padding: 30px 0px 80px 0px;
    }

    .left .content{
    padding-right: 140px;
    }
    .right .content{
      padding-left: 140px
    }
    .right{
    text-align: left;
  left: 50%;


    }

.right:after {
    left: -104px;
    }
```

I think this is called a timeline, there is a lot of tutorials talking about how to do something like this, but I don't know how to make the images in the timeline line. Can you please help me do this?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant for asking ready-made solutions. Please provide minimal code of what you have already tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree @Henrdy comment. you have to open PSD file using app like gimp, export like a png and learn HTML and CSS to put all together in a web page.

Comment: @Hendry Ok thank you for replying, I will try to put the code.

Comment: @Leonardo Saracini I didn't understand your answer very much. I'm using photoshop to open my PSD file. I converted three sections to HTML and css, but I don't know how to convert this part. thank you for your comment ^^.

Comment: Sorry I have not understand your question very well.  You ask for convert PSD but you haven't describe your question enough to let me a clear view on your problem.

Comment: @LeonardoSaracini I made some changes. I added my html and css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build this, you could use css grid layout (guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Treat each of the content+image as a row in the layout. And each row as a container for a grid.

You can visually break every row down to 3 columns. One column for left-side content, the second one for the image and the third one for right-side content.

Example css grid for a layout like this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 10em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "content-left image content-right";
  text-align: center;
}

.content-left { grid-area: content-left; background: lightblue; }

.image { grid-area: image; background: lightgreen; }

.content-right { grid-area: content-right; background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="content-left">Left content</div>
  <div class="image">Image</div>
  <div class="content-right">Right content</div>
</div>
```

(grid generated with: https://grid.layoutit.com/)

To alternate between content on the left and on the right, you can use css even/odd selectors ([How can I style even and odd elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements)) to set which grid area is used for the element.

#### Example:

I've built an example of a timeline layout for this answer which you can find at https://codepen.io/hendrysadrak/pen/VwLEraz

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent all day trying to find a solution. I didn't think we can achieve this with grid.

Comment: @Gangelo Glad to help out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="about">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div id="col1" class="col right">
                  <h5>JULY 2010<br> Our Humble Beginnings</h5>
                  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum officia labore fugit nihil nulla laboriosam praesentium harum ut, odio ea facere, recusandae reprehenderit repellat.</p>

              </div>
             <div id="col2" class="col"><img class="img" src="assets/img/about-1.png"/></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row2" >
              <div id="col3" class="col"><img class="img" src="assets/img/about-1.png"/></div>
              <div id="col4" class="col left">
                  <h5>JULY 2010<br> Our Humble Beginnings</h5>
                  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum officia labore fugit nihil nulla laboriosam praesentium harum ut, odio ea facere, recusandae reprehenderit repellat.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

in main.css file:

```css
   .about .wrapper{
        padding: 80px 10%;
        text-align: center;

    }
    .about h5{
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 1em;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
    }

    .row {
      width: 59%;
      margin-right: 41%;
      display: flex;
    }
    .row2 {
      width: 59%;
      display: flex;
      margin-left: 41%;
    }
    .col {
      flex:1;    
    }
    .col.left {
      text-align: left;
    }
    .col.right {
      text-align: right;    
    }
    #col2 {
      flex-basis: 30%;
    }
    #col1 { 
      flex-basis: 70%;    
    }
    #col3 {
      flex-basis: 30%;
    }
    #col4 { 
      flex-basis: 70%;    
    }
    .img {
        margin: 10% 5%;
        width: 90%;
        border-radius: 50%;
     }

     #container {
      background-image: linear-gradient(lightgrey,lightgrey);
      background-size: 2px 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
     }
```

[image: assets/img/about-1.png]
put this in assets/img/about-1.png