# How to set row odd/even formatting in HTML code

Tags: html

I am trying to pass row formatting in below code, but some how that is not happening.

```html
<style>
a { text-decoration: none; } a:link { color: #200772; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; } a:hover { color: #FF8000; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; } table { margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse; color: #0d0c0c; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; } th { font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #f7f9fa; font-weight: normal; background-color: #0a1ef7; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin: 0; padding: 4px 10px 4px 5px; text-align: left; } td { color: #0d0c0c; font: 8pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; margin: 0; /* padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; */ padding: 8px 20px 5px 5px; } td.userinput { color: #0d0c0c; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; } td.errormsg { color: red; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; } td.msg { color: #747170; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; } #t01 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee;}#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff;}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I style even and odd elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well. But there is an important point. The pseudo-classes `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` are responsible for assigning styles to the even and odd selectors. They are in your css, but they are preceded by an identifier(`#t01`) that does not exist in the code. I commented it out.

```css
a { text-decoration: none; } 

a:link { color: #200772; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; } 

a:hover { color: #FF8000; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; } 

table { margin: 0; border-collapse: collapse; color: #0d0c0c; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; }

th { font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #f7f9fa; font-weight: normal; background-color: #0a1ef7; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin: 0; padding: 4px 10px 4px 5px; text-align: left; } 

td { color: #0d0c0c; font: 8pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; margin: 0; /* padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; */ padding: 8px 20px 5px 5px; }

td.userinput { color: #0d0c0c; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; } 

td.errormsg { color: red; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; } 

td.msg { color: #747170; font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 6px 20px 1px 0; } 

/*#t01*/ tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee;}

/*#t01*/ tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <td><a href="">1.1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>2</th>
  <td><a href="">2.1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>3</th>
  <td><a href="">3.1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>4</th>
  <td><a href="">4.1</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>5</th>
  <td><a href="">5.1</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I can’t. This isn’t my question. You’ll have to ask vijay

Comment: exactly)) did not pay attention to the name of the commentator. sorry

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, while looking preview of results its showing the formatting but when I am sending email using results using SMTP email only showing header formatting not for rows any suggestions.

Comment: When I am looking to the email which I received based on this HTML code, I am able to see all formatting except rows , I copied the source of email & test it into online HTML test editor its showing rows with formatting :-( not sure what is the missing bit here which not allowing to see the formatting in email.

Comment: just now reading one article which saying odd/even is not compatible with IE 8 & email using IE 8 compatibility.  I tried below code but thats also not helping.
/*#t01*/ tr:nth-child(1n)  {background-color: #cacacc;} /*#t01*/ tr:nth-child(2n) {background-color: #f7f7fa;}

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, did you get chance to look into this please.

Answer (score 1):

For each row, let's say it's `<div>`

Then do this:

```css
div:nth-child(odd) {
background: grey;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
background: white;
}
```

Comment: Your contributions are welcome on Stack Overflow, however when a question already has an answer (like this one) on the site, then the correct action is to flag it as a duplicate, so that the site doesn't get cluttered with redundant questions that have already been answered :) Please take a look at [the "Answered well-asked question" section of How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future reference,

Comment: Thanks for the tip @FluffyKitten! Will do that now.