# How to change even li text color to green and odd to red?

Tags: javascript, dom

In my html, I have ol and 10 li. I need to change the even number li color to green and odd number li to red using only Javascript.

How can I do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Color Change</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements.

Comment: My assignment was to use only javascript.

Comment: So you have an assignment and you are asking people to do it for you ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
li {
    color: black;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```