# Dynamic HTML Classes PHP and WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, class, dynamic

Can you please advise which is the most appropriate way to append classes dynamically to the 's below based on the ID of the post?

The goal is to add a class to some of the div's depending on the ID of the post being even or odd.

```
<div class="service__preview">
<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 // here I want to dynamically add order-2 if get_the_ID() is even">
                <div class="service__preview service__preview-id">
                    <?php echo get_the_ID() + 1;?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 // here I want to dynamically add order-1 if get_the_ID() is even">
                <div class="service__preview service__preview-icon">
                    <div class="icon__container icon__container-3x">
                        <div class="icon__container icon__container-2x">
                            <div class="icon__container icon__container-1x">
                                <i class="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'service_icon', true); ?> fa-2x"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <a class="service__preview service__preview-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <p class="service__preview service__preview-description"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <a class="service__preview service__preview-link" href=" <?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p>Learn more</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looking forward to your suggestions.

FYI: the project is a WordPress template.

Comment: What PHP code have you put into Wordpress to make that happen?

Comment: Is a simple `mod` good enough? `echo get_the_ID() % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';`

Comment: @ChrisHaas, is that the most appropriate way? Or would it be better from a performance point of view if I'd create two php components which shall be rendered dynamically for items with even and odd IDs?

Comment: @hppycoder, not sure I understand what code you reffer to?

Comment: This whole thing is predicated on the fact that `get_the_ID()` will be sequential. That could be possible but in my experience is unlikely. If the odd/even is for display purposes then just use [CSS nth-child selectors](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) to alter the appearance.

Comment: For this case I’d say it is the most appropriate. That function is a very lightweight wrapper so it shouldn’t have an performance issues. That said, I can’t imagine the use case for this. Post IDs are not guaranteed to be sequential. I would think [CSS even/odd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080787/231316) would be a better experience

Comment: Hah, @hppycoder, same thoughts exactly!

Comment: lol! I know I was just thinking that @ChrisHaas

Comment: @AlexandruAna you will get a lot further going with the odd/even rules than trying to do this using data from WordPress.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions! I will go with the CSS even/odd recommendation.