# How to select all items in even rows using css nth-child(formula)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a couple of items aligned in a flex container 3 on each row as on the image.[image: my grid] How do I select all items in even rows (row 2, 4, ...) - shaded items - using an :nth-child formula

For example, if I wanted to select all items in the second column, I would have done something like: `:nth-child(3n - 1)`. But I can't figure out a formula to select all the items in even rows.

I thought of `:nth-child(3n + 1)` but It will select only the first items from every row.

Edit: For those who required some HTML code.

```css
div.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 16px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.flex-container > div {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(95% / 3);
  height: 80px;
  background-color: indigo;
  margin: 16px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

/*NOT WORKING. This is select all elements at even position. But I want to select all items in even rows*/
div.flex-container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>  
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
  <div>5</div>  
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>  
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>  
  <div>11</div>  
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>  
  <div>15</div>  
  <div>16</div>  
  <div>17</div>  
  <div>18</div>
</div>
```

Edit 2: I created this snippet from Preetam Vishwakarma's answer suggesting: `:nth-child(6n + 4)`, `:nth-child(6n + 5)`, `:nth-child(6n + 6)`. Can it be **more dynamic**?. This will work only with a three-columns. Can we make it in a single equation?

```css
div.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 16px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.flex-container > div {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(95% / 3);
  height: 80px;
  background-color: indigo;
  margin: 16px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

/*Can it be **more dynamic**?. This will work only with a three-columns. Can we make it in a single equation?*/
div.flex-container > div:nth-child(6n + 4), div.flex-container > div:nth-child(6n + 5), div.flex-container > div:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>  
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
  <div>5</div>  
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>  
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>  
  <div>11</div>  
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>  
  <div>15</div>  
  <div>16</div>  
  <div>17</div>  
  <div>18</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I style even and odd elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements)

Comment: Please, post some code, it depends on your html too

Comment: So this is a single element that wraps creating rows, correct?

Comment: @dalelandry yes all the items are in a single element; a flex container.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro No it doesn't. I'm not trying to select all elements at even or odd positions. Please read the question. I want to select all elements that are in even rows.

Comment: you cannnot do this with one selector, you will need 3

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior, now that you posted the code, the question is much more clear. Can you not include an extra div to actually create your rows? Maybe the easiest answer for you is in the HTML and not in the CSS.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro No, because I won't need three columns per row at all viewports.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 :nth-child(6n + 4)
 :nth-child(6n + 5)
 :nth-child(6n + 6)
```

Comment: thanks. This will work but is it possible to have it in one equation?

Answer (score -2):

Use :nth-child(even) selector.

Comment: This is not correct. it's going to select all items at an even position. That is 2, 4, 6, 8 ... That's not what I want. Please read the question