# Using AJAX to GET a PHP file in my HTML document, but the scripts inside it aren't working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom

I am calling a **php** file, into my HTML document using **AJAX**, and it is working too. The problem is that, there are few ***script*** tags in that PHP files, which works just fine if the PHP files is viewed individually. But when I call it using AJAX, those scripts are not functioning.

I am attaching my PHP code, and the screenshots below.

***trial.php***

```
<script>
document.getElementById("response1").onload = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ffa31a";
}

</script>

<h1 class="restitle"> Responses</h1>

<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "portfolio";

    $conn = mysqli_connect( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

    if ( !$conn ) {
        die( "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
    }

    $sql = "SELECT NAME, EMAIL, MESSAGE, TIME FROM Feedback ORDER BY TIME";
    $result=$conn->query( $sql );

    if ( $result == TRUE ) {
        $i=0;
?>

<script>
    var n = 1;
</script>

<?php
        
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) {
        $i = $i+1;
      
        echo "<div class='response' id='response$i'><h1 class='responsetitle' id='responsetitle$i'><i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> " . $row[0]. " <span class='responseemail' id='responseemail$i'> (". $row[1] .")</h1><hr class='responseline'><p class='responsetxt' id='responsetxt$i'>\"" . $row[2] . "\"</p><br /><div class='responsetimecontain'><span class='responsetime'>- " . $row[3] . "</span></div></div>";
      
        echo "<div id='valuepipe$i' style='display:none;'>" . $i . "</div>";
      
?>

<script>
    var i = document.getElementById("valuepipe" + n).textContent;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById("response" + n).style.backgroundColor = "#ffa31a";
        document.getElementById("responseemail" + n).style.color = "#f2f2f2";
        document.getElementById("responseemail" + n).style.opacity = "0.6";

        document.getElementById("responsetitle" + n).childNodes[0].style.color = "#f2f2f2";
        document.getElementById("responsetxt" + n).style.color = "#f2f2f2";
    }
    n++;
</script>

<?php
        }
    $result -> free_result();
    }
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

mysqli_close( $conn );

?>
```

When this file is viewed individually:

[image: When Opened Directly]

But when I call it using AJAX:

```
<script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("main2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "trial.php");
    xhttp.send();

</script>
```

I get the following view :

[image: Called using AJAX]

Somehow all the ***script*** tags are being ignored or something. Need a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

*Note: The other styles are implemented in my CSS file, so they are visible. Only the Scripts are not working*

Comment: Looks the same to me, except one has a different background color, which might be [possible in pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080787/231316). Regardless, compare the rendered DOM

Comment: The AJAX's return contains javascript which sets CSS (backgroundColor / color / opacity), but please note that the return of ajax itself will not be executed / rendered. Hence, please do a re-rendering on completion of the ajax in your parent script. The normal way is to do the rendering is put them in `http.onreadystatechange` (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)

Comment: yeah man use css for this. `.some-class:nth-child(odd)`, `.some-class:nth-child(even)`

Comment: better to write a css class for n%2 element and apply the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> HTML5 specifies that a <script> tag inserted with innerHTML should not execute.

You'll need to separate the scripts from the HTML content and either include them as part of the code that loads the content, or place them in their own script file that is loaded separately.