# Tampermonkey remove element

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have the following HTML structure, that I need to remove some DIVs:

```
<body>
<div data-ng-include="'banner.html'" class="ng-scope">
 <div data-ng-view class="ng-scope">
  <div wcs-line status-line="statuses" class="flex-container ng-isolate-scope">

   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 1</div>

   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 2</div>

   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 3</div>
```

The website contains a lot of boxes from DATA 1 to DATA 1000 and I have to remove all boxes that are ODD numbers. so basically in the above code, DATA 1 and DATA 3 need to be removed.

I have the below code for Greasemonkey, tried to remove all boxes first, but it doesn't work. I haven't even got to the point to select even or odd number.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
var $ = window.jQuery;

var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);

function letsJQuery() {   
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box-container');
for (const box of boxes) {
  box.classList.remove('flex-item', 'ng-scope');
}
```

Any clue would be very helpful!! Thanks!

Comment: Do the boxes actually have to be removed from the DOM, or would hiding them be enough? A single CSS rule would be enough to hide them, e.g. using something like [How can I style even and odd elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements)

Comment: Need to be removed. Hiding them would cause an empty space between boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the HTML structure being used in your example (without all of the closing tags I can't be sure how it is actually set up/displaying), so I am going to focus on removing `box-container` elements containing odd numbers. If you need to remove additional elements, there are several ways to find/select those elements as well but I would need to see a more complete HTML structure.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".box-container").forEach(el => {
  if(parseInt(el.textContent.match(/\d+/ig).join("")) % 2 != 0) el.remove();
});
```

```html
<div data-ng-include="'banner.html'" class="ng-scope">
 <div data-ng-view class="ng-scope">
  <div wcs-line status-line="statuses" class="flex-container ng-isolate-scope">

   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 1</div>

   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 2</div>

   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 3</div>
     
   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 4</div>
     
   <div ng-repeat="data" class="flex-item ng-scope">
   <div class="box-container">DATA 5</div>
     
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

The above code loops through all of the `box-container` elements (as these seem to contain the text/numbers) and parses the text to get the number value. From there, using a modulus operator we can determine if the number is odd or not and remove the current element if it is odd.

Comment: Just tried, not working. how can we query select all the DIVs that are like this?
<div wcs-line line-statuses="statuses" class="flex-container ng-isolate-scope">
If you notice, there is two words in class. How we select all DIVs that have the 2 same words in their class?

Comment: @user15109593 I would need to see how you are actually trying to implement this. The code snippet posted works as intended so this implies your actual code must be different in some way (likely the HTML). But, to query all elements with those two classes you would just use `document.querySelectorAll(".flex-container.ng-isolate-scope")` instead.