# Using :nth-child(odd/even) selector to change background color

Tags: html, css

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/how-can-i-style-even-and-odd-elements) as a reference, not really sure why it isn't working. Is there something i'm missing? I also tried using :nth-of-type(1 and 2 respectively), still no luck.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.main-block {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.icon-block {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon-block:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}

.icon-block:nth-child(even) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-block">
    <div class="icon-block">
      <i>Lorem ipsum</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block">
    <div class="icon-block">
      <i>Lorem ipsum</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both of your `.icon-block` elements are the first, last, and only child of their respective parent elements. You want to apply this on the level of `.main-block`.

Comment: I don't want to apply it onto the parent rather the child elements, so how would I select the child elements instead (.icon-block). I tried it like this too, but it didn't work: .main-block .icon-block:nth-child(odd) and vice versa.

Comment: You need to apply the pseudo class on the level, where you actually _have_ multiple children. I did not say that you can not proceed to then select elements _inside_ those odd/even children you selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.main-block {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.icon-block {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-block:nth-child(odd) .icon-block {
  background: blue;
}

.main-block:nth-child(even) .icon-block {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-block">
    <div class="icon-block">
      <i>Lorem ipsum</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block">
    <div class="icon-block">
      <i>Lorem ipsum</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem was that you were targeting `.icon-block` directly, and they were both first in their parent `.main-block`.